# What are the major differences between the Combat Drone and the Turret techs?

Tags: mass-effect-3

The Engineer has access to a Combat Drone and a Turret. There seems to be some minor differences between the two but they share a cooldown. Is there a reason to spec one over the other? Should leveling both abilities be avoided since they share a cooldown and perform a similar function?

Comment: Drone moves. Turret doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than the fact that [drones](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Combat_Drone) can move and [turrets](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Sentry_Turret) don't as Raven pointed out, here are the other major differences:

- The base drone damage is higher 40 to 25 and the drone gets more potential damage/shield upgrades.
- The turret can potentially get an ammo effect (AP or cryo) and a flamethrower (high close up dps)
- The drone can get an explosive effect when it dies and chain lightning (stun multiple targets)

The combat drone is offensively oriented and seems to be typically way better at distracting large targets than the turret as it can, and will, move in close and start zapping away.  The turret is a lot more defensively oriented, designed to hold one spot on the battlefield or protect your flanks, etc.

Comment: I noticed the drone seems to appear as far away from you as is required to spawn behind your target and start shooting him in the back. Really useful against those riot-shield enemies. The turret seems to just go bounce on the ground and look sad.